# Cannot delete printer from control panel via Win32 API on Windows 8.1 and Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, printing, wmi

I'm trying to delete the printer entry from Windows programmatically and it seems to work with TCP/IP printers but not with assigned to USB port. Actually, the printer entry disappears from Win32_Printer WMI collection but it still exists in "Control Panel - Devices and Printers". It has only name there without driver and additional info assigned.
I was trying to do this via ManagementScope and via "DeletePrinter" Print Spooler API method. My code snippets:

ManagementScope:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
scope.Connect();
SelectQuery query = new SelectQuery("select * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '" + printerName + "'");
ManagementObjectSearcher search = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection printersCollection = search.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject printer in printersCollection)
   printer.Delete();
```

DeletePrinter:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool DeletePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int OpenPrinter(string pPrinterName, out IntPtr phPrinter, IntPtr pDefault);

private static bool DeletePrinter(string printerName)
{
   var pd = new PRINTER_DEFAULTS { DesiredAccess = 8 | 4 | 0x000F0000 };
   var rawsize = Marshal.SizeOf(pd);
   var pdPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawsize);
   Marshal.StructureToPtr(pd, pdPtr, true);
   IntPtr hPrinter;
   if (OpenPrinter(printerName, out hPrinter, pdPtr) != 0)
   {
      if (hPrinter != IntPtr.Zero)
      {
         var result = DeletePrinter(hPrinter);
         ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
         return result;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue. 
I've created support incident for Microsoft and they confirmed it is a bug in OS.